# Disable temporary user profile on workstations in a Windows 2008 env

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-management, roaming-profile, user-profile

I have a Windows 2008 domain with +/- 27 workstations. The users have all roaming profiles, but this doesn't work sometimes. What results in that the user is logging in with a temp user profile instead.

Is there a way to **disable** the temp user profile? In my opinion it's useless to have a temp user profile because the user doesn't get his/hers work files, so they are unable to work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the group policy setting "Do not log users on with temporary profiles", to be found in Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates-> System -> User Profiles.

Comment: Thx man! More precise: Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates-> System -> User Profiles -> Do not log users on with temporary profiles.