# Prevent Temp user creation in windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, user-management, windows-10, user-profile

Windows creating temp profile every time when I login to the PC. The pc has more than one user. I am facing this problem in many Windows 10 and Server 2012 PC's. The temp profile creation is not found in every user. But, in most of the cases it is there.

The Windows 10 is the free upgraded version. Initially, the case was less. Now recently the frequency of the error is increased.

Sometimes this will be solved if I log off and log in again. But, after 2-3 days again this repeats.

Installed Antivirus software: Symantec Endpoint Security, Norton Security and in some PCs Windows Defender.

I have also tried by removing all the services from ‘Services.msc’. But, not solved. I was using Windows 8 and 8.1 as Desktop OS previously and same software and hardware were being used in that also. But, this error was not found before.

**Tried solutions:**
Searched in the internet about the error and found some solutions but none of them worked for me.

1. Contacted Microsoft support and they tried doing disk cleanup of C drive.
2. Deleted the temp created folder and changed the temp profile created in the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.
3. Enabled the "Do not log users on with temporary profiles" in the group policy as mensioned in [Disable temporary user profile on workstations in a Windows 2008 env](https://serverfault.com/questions/309692/disable-temporary-user-profile-on-workstations-in-a-windows-2008-env)

All the steps done above did not work instead when I did the 3rd solution I got error when logging in saying "User Profile Service failed the sign-in. User Profile cannot be loaded." Now when I search for this error I got the same result as above mentioned options in Google.

Please help to solve this error and prevent from happening in the future.

**Update:**

When the OS creates the temp profile I can see 2 logs written in event viewer, which says:

1. Windows has backed up this user profile. Windows will automatically try to use the backup profile the next time this user logs on.
2. Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.

Comment: This should probably be on superuser.

Comment: The question is put on the super user as suggested. http://superuser.com/questions/1183139/prevent-temp-user-creation-in-windows